# Move blogger homepage to custom URL

Tags: url, blog, blogger, blogspot

My Blogger blog is `example.com`. I tried to make my homepage URL as  `example.com/euphoria` but couldn't find a way to do it through googling. I came to know that it not possible to create subfolder in blogger (`domain.com/blog`) where every URL starts with `domain.com/blog`. That was disappointing then I changed my mind and tried to find a way to change only the URL of the homepage. Yes only the homepage URL as  `example.com/euphoria` I want the default homepage with latest post and signup form to be placed in  `example.com/euphoria` I guess this can be done as blogger have feature like redirection and pages. If you know any ways which can help me to achieve my goal please help me by answering to the question.

Note: It is blogger blog (`domain.blogspot.com`) where I use custom domain.

Comment: I think it can be possible only if you have site on your custom domain.

Comment: i have custom domain. but the problem is blogger only allow subdomain blog.example.com i am trying to make my homepage with url example.com/blog If you know any methods please reply

Comment: Blogger will not allow to do that. If you have custom domain and using wordpress to setup blog then you can do that sub folder setup.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a page, and have your so-called "home page" as example.com/p/yourPage.html

To achieve this:

1. Make a page   (Dashboard > Pages > New page) with the content you want on your "home page" and "yourPage" as the title.
2. Set up a new custom redirect (Dashboard > Settings > Search Preferences > Custom Redirects )  from    "/"   to "/p/yourPage.html"

Note:   there is no way to get rid of the /p/   in the page address.   But some people don't mind having it there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Even if you were able to setup a redirection, Google Blogger doesn't allow for subfolders to exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to use a directory like `example.com/blog` with Blogger, but you can use a subdomain like `blog.example.com`.   [Here is a tutorial](http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2010/03/sub-domain-on-blogger-custom-domain.html) that walks you through setting it up.